# Electrocaloric effect around object?

Tags: electrostatics

This UFO was photographed with an infrared camera from a US navy fighter in 2015. In the second half of the video objects with hot temperatures are black and objects with cooler temperatures are white.

https://youtu.be/2TumprpOwHY

The UFO seems to have a white halo around it possibly indicating cooler air.

Could this phenomenon be due to the cooling effect of a high strength electric field around the object ([electrocaloric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocaloric_effect))? Or is it simply some form of glare in the infrared camera?

**Better explanation for aura effect**

Skeptic Mike West explains the aura around the UFO. He says it’s due to an image sharpening filter.

https://youtu.be/r119JWI04Ls

---

**Clarification**

This question solely adresses the question of whether a strong electric field around an object could produce a glare as shown in the first video when recorded with an IR camera. This is a question which can be answered without needing to adress the question of whether the filmed object *actually* is some kind of UFO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is pure speculation. With the available input the question can not be properly discussed with the rigour required for an answer based on physics.

Comment: I think that the actual question is a good one and can be answered with facts. I would only consider the question of what the object is speculative, but this is not topic of this post.

Comment: @JohnEastmond I have made an attempt to clarify what I perceived as the main question and focus more on the physics rather than the "UFO". Feel free to rollback or modify if you wish!

Answer (score -1):

I think the military have used some sort of drone to see how well it camouflages when cold jets of gas are used to condense water droplets. There are some small jets coming out of the top and bottom of the disc which you can see if you magnify  a photo of it on your computer. These may be jets of cold gas.